# what `B5s` mean when print Duration in golang, using %v

Tags: go

```
glog.Info("%v", time.Now().Sub(t1))
```

will output:`11.302B5s`

What does `B5s` mean?

Comment: Are you sure it actually print this? As pointed out below this is probably a display problem on your side.

Answer (score 5):

I think it comes from `U+00B5`, i.e. [µ (micro)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00b5/index.htm). It looks like it is trying to [print microseconds](https://golang.org/src/time/time.go?s=15077:15110#L490).